# How to map a JSON list to Virtus Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have this JSON like:

```
[
{
  "id": 1,
  "createdAt": "2014-05-08T18:05:09-03:00",
  "updatedAt": "2014-05-08T18:05:09-03:00",
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "createdAt": "2014-05-08T18:08:39-03:00",
  "updatedAt": "2014-05-08T18:08:39-03:00",
}
]
```

I'm trying to map this return for a [Virtus model](https://github.com/solnic/virtus). My model is like:

```
class OrdersCollection
  include Virtus.model

  attribute :list, Array[OrderCollectionItem]
end

class OrderCollectionItem
  include Virtus.model

  attribute :id
end
```

The `list` attribute is always empty, and I couldn't find out why.

Can someone help me understand how can I map this in a better way?

It keeps returning me: `NoMethodError. Expected response.body to respond to #to_hash`

Comment: What you have is not a valid JSON - try `[{"id":1,...},{"id":2,...}]`

Comment: @UriAgassi.  Thanks but now it's returning `NoMethodError. Expected response.body to respond to #to_hash`

Comment: Sorry. I did reject by mistake your last edit that includes the solution.

Comment: @Larry I've added again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON isn't formatted correctly.  You aren't defining the list attribute in your JSON so Virtus doesn't know how to map to it correctly.  Try formatting it like this:

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "createdAt": "2014-05-08T18:05:09-03:00",
      "updatedAt": "2014-05-08T18:05:09-03:00",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "createdAt": "2014-05-08T18:08:39-03:00",
      "updatedAt": "2014-05-08T18:08:39-03:00",
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Right now I've updated the code with the right formatting plus the entire [json](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/50f1daa0daebeecc8401). It's already right. And I'm receiving from a 3-party. I can't edit its json

Comment: After you parse out the JSON you should have an array.  You need to define the `list` attribute.  `hash = {list: parsed_json}`

Comment: Thanks! It's working. But there's a array of represent my model without this list added in the parsed json?

Comment: You probably don't need OrdersCollection, Just loop over your parsed array and create OrderCollectionItem for each element.

Comment: I don't think iterate will be better. The final solution was: `hash = {list: response.body}
      orders_collection = OrdersCollection.new(hash)`